# How not to send information until a strong password is selected?

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hooks, material-ui

I have use **PasswordStrengthBar** .How can I check that the request is not sent until the strong password is entered...In fact, I want it not to be sent if the password is weak
I use **useform**..

```
<Grid container className={classes.inputItem}>
  <Grid item>
    <Input
      name="newPassword"
      type={state.new ? "text" : "password"}
      inputClassName={classes.Input}
      ref={register({ required: true })}
      error={!!errors.newPassword}
      endAdornment={
        <PasswordAdornment
          onClick={(visible) => dispatch({ field: "new", visible })}
        />
      }
    />
    <PasswordStrengthBar
      name="PasswordStrength"
      password={watch("newPassword")}
      minLength={6}
      barColors={barColors}
      scoreWordClassName={classes.scoreWordClassName}
    />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Do you mean this password strength bar component? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-password-strength-bar

Comment: yes `import PasswordStrengthBar from "react-password-strength-bar";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [react-password-strength-bar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-password-strength-bar) component [has an `onChangeScore`](https://github.com/lannex/react-password-strength-bar/blob/35ae1ea7e12ebaaef396eb17cfb2bf07e6594dc6/lib/index.tsx#L23) prop.

You can add something like

```
<PasswordStrengthBar
    name="PasswordStrength"
    ...
    onChangeScore={(score) => setCanSubmit(score >= 4)}
/>
```

or similar (depending on how you're managing state). Obviously you'll want to set that `canSubmit` flag to false to begin with, so people will need to enter a password.